# Can't get Selenium drag and drop test to work (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to perform Selenium's dragAndDrop function in Java. Right now, i'm testing with this page. It contains an image and two divs:

[image]

I'm trying to test dragging the image to just the green div for now. I was able to come up with this Java code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://localhost:8012/dragTest/dragAndDropTest.html");

    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //Element to be dragged
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"drag1\"]")).click();
    WebElement from = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"drag1\"]"));

    //Element to drag to
    WebElement to = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"div1\"]"));

    //Use Action class for drag and drop
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

    //Drag and drop drag1 to div1
    builder.dragAndDrop(from, to).perform();
    builder.build();
}
```

I'm able to run the test, but nothing happens. I added console logs to test if the code even clicks on the image prior to dragging, and that works (the clicking works), it's just the image doesn't get dragged.

I've looked around for help and noticed that a lot of drag and drop Selenium code look like this. So I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
builder.dragAndDrop(from, to).perform();
builder.build();
```

Try:

```
builder.dragAndDrop(from, to).build().perform();
```

I think this should work.